# React.js: Add/Remove input field on click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

React.js:  Add/Remove input field on click of a button:

When a user click Add, I want a new input field to be added.

The name property is changing for every input, by increment the number in the middle:

document-0-document
document-1-document

I receive the following error:

"TypeError: this is undefined var arr = this.state.documents;"

I have an idea what is creating the error but I didn't found a fix.

HTML Code.

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <input type="file" name="document-0-document">
  <div class="more-documents">
    <input type="file" name="document-1-document">
    <button data-reactid=".0.1">Add</button>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Main Component code:

```
class DocumentsFieldSet extends Component{

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {documents:[]}
  }

  add(i) {
      var arr  = this.state.documents;
      arr.push(i);
      this.setState({documents: arr});
  }

  eachDocument () {
      return <DocumentInput key={i}/>
  }

  render (){
      return (
        <div>
            {this.state.documents.map(this.eachDocument)}
            <button onClick={this.add.bind()}>Add</button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DocumentsFieldSet/>, document.querySelector ('.more-    documents'))
```

Component Code

```
class DocumentInput extends Component {
  render() {
      return <input type="file" name="document-{i}-document" ref="" />;
  }
}

export default DocumentInput;
```

Comment: What you want to add?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your example

1. You need bind `this` for `.add` method
2. You don't put to `this.state.documents` array index
3. Inside `DocumentInput` there is no `i` variable

```js
class DocumentInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input 
      type="file" 
      name={ `document-${ this.props.index }-document` } 
    />;
  }
}

class DocumentsFieldSet extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      documents: []
    }
    
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  add() {
    const documents = this.state.documents.concat(DocumentInput);
    this.setState({ documents });
  }
  
  render () {
    const documents = this.state.documents.map((Element, index) => {
      return <Element key={ index } index={ index } />
    });

    return <div>
      <button onClick={ this.add }>Add</button>
    
      <div className="inputs">
        { documents }
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DocumentsFieldSet />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.inputs {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Delete particular filed set after clicking add button just like + -. Is it possible.

Comment: Can you help me, how to delete component using index ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot to pass context into [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function.

replace

```
<button onClick={this.add.bind()}>Add</button>
```

to

```
<button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Add</button>
```

Comment: This is the right answer, why has this been downvoted?

Comment: I understand that it's not ideal, because it will create a brand new function on every single render, but it's correct! :)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti you're right but I've just fixed his problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your `add` function as an arrow function. It would bind function to `this` for you. Read more about it [here](http://moduscreate.com/how-to-use-es6-arrow-functions-with-react-native/)

```
add = (i) => {
    var arr = this.state.documents;
    arr.push(i);
    this.setState({documents: arr});
};
```

Also I would rewrite your function to be:

```
add = (i) => {
    const { documents } = this.state;
    documents.push(i);
    this.setState({ documents });
};
```

Comment: This is a [class field](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-public-fields), it's not part of ES2015 and has to manually enabled in `.babelrc` by adding `stage-1` or `transform-class-properties`